# What do all of the stats icons represent?

Tags: army-of-ruin

Wondering what each of the stats in the panel displayed on the pause screen represent.  A few of them I recognize, but not nearly all of them.

[image: Stats panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found most of them.
Based on your screenshot, those icons are:

| STATS |  |
| --- | --- |
| Health | ? |
| Speed | Experience |
| Pickup range | Skill |
| Interests | Luck |
| Extra life |  |
| Damage | ? |
| Projectiles | Size |
| Duration | Projectile speed |
| ? |  |

Here's an handy recap:

[image]